# Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu Animation Direction on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the default slide in direction of the navigation menu when the toggle icon ("hamburger icon") is pressed?

I would like to achieve an effect similar to the one www.shopify.com is using on mobile version of their website: http://d.pr/v/1iEUF (here is a short video presentation of what I am trying to achieve).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (thats **not** an external link) (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: When I want something to slide in from the left/right instead of top/bottom I usually animate the width. You can set the menu to position: absolute; right: 0; width: 0; and then toggle a class that sets the width to 100%.

Comment: check my Demo u will learn from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to build that style

JS

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass('right');
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('indexcity');
    });
});
```

I already reupdated the demo, the effect that you wanted i already get the way u posted before.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/fk63zzbz/3/)

Comment: Hi Fliido93, thank you very much for your reply, this is exactly what I was looking for! ;) Added it to my project, everything seems to work smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/t2h1ya1z/
If you spend some more time, the code can be optimized to minimum number of lines.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-toggle"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="slidemenu">
            <a class="close">X</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page-content">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="no-margin-top">Left Sidebar menu</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body.slide-active {
    overflow-x: hidden
}
#page-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;
    left: 0;
}
#page-content.slide-active {
    padding-top: 0
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 17px 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
    background: #CC0F0F;
    color: #CC0F0F;
}
.navbar-header {
    position: relative
}
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: relative
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #slide-nav .container {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80%;
        top: -1px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        left: -100%;
        min-width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        top: -8px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 80%;
        white-space: normal;
    }
    #slide-nav {
        border-top: 0
    }
    #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
        background: #333
    }
    #navbar-height-col {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #f7f7f7;
    }
    #navbar-height-col.inverse {
        background: #333;
        z-index: 1;
        border: 0;
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 8px 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*fast clearfixer*/
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
        text-align: center
    }
    #slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
        width: 100%
    }
    #slidemenu .close {
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #page-content {
        left: 0 !important
    }
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
        position: fixed
    }
    .navbar-header {
        left: 0 !important
    }
}
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-inverse').after($('<div class="inverse" id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
    $('#slide-nav.navbar-default').after($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

    var slidewidth = '20%';
    var navbarneg = '-' + slidewidth;

    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('#navbar-height-col').css("width", slidewidth);
        $('#navbar-height-col').css("left", navbarneg);
        $('#slide-nav #slidemenu').css("width", slidewidth);
        $('#slide-nav #slidemenu').css("left", navbarneg);
    }
    $('#slidemenu .close').on('click', function() {
        var selected = $('#slidemenu').hasClass('slide-active');
        $('#slidemenu, .navbar-toggle, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');
        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left : selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
        });
        $('.inverse').stop().animate({
            left : selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
        });

        //alert(1);
    });

    $("#slide-nav").on("click", '.navbar-toggle', function(e) {

        // slider is active
        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

        // set slidemenu width
        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left : selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
        });

        // set navbar width
        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left : selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
        });

        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');

        $('.navbar,  .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');
    });

    var selected = '#slidemenu .navbar, .navbar-header';

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }
    });
});
```